# This calculator using form submission to satisfy variables isn't working

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to make a calculator in order to... well, calculate something. Anyway, I am trying to make 4 variables be set too 4 user inputs by using form submission. However, no matter what I do, I can't get the variables to get set. Help would be appreciated!

```html
   

    <!DOCTYPEhtml>
<html>
<head>
<title>NatHisCalc</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1><center><b><p>Test</p></b></center></h1>
<center><b><p id='output'>loading...</p></b></center>
<center><b><p id='output2'>loading...</p></b></center>
<center><b><p id='output3'>loading...</p></b></center>
<center><b><p id='output4'>loading...</p></b></center>
<form id="a" action="/action_page.php">
  Input X <input type="number" name="x"><br><br>
  <input type="button" onclick="calc()" value="Submit">
</form>
<form id="a" action="/action_page.php">
  Input X <input type="number" name="y"><br><br>
  <input type="button" onclick="calc()" value="Submit">
</form>
<form id="a" action="/action_page.php">
  Input X <input type="number" name="a"><br><br>
  <input type="button" onclick="calc()" value="Submit">
</form>
<form id="a" action="/action_page.php">
  Input X <input type="number" name="b"><br><br>
  <input type="button" onclick="calc()" value="Submit">
</form>
<script>
function calc() {
var x = document.getElementById("x").submit();
var y = document.getElementById("y").submit();
var a = document.getElementById("a").submit();
var b = document.getElementById("b").submit();
var u = (0.101*(y/100))*(480000*(a/100))            
var j = (0.581*(x/100))*(120000*(b/100))  
if (x > 150 || x < 50) {
window.alert('Hold on... Those inputs will result in an unreasonable output. You can click ');
}
var preresult = j + u;
if (preresult < 177000) {
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 'Test';
} else {
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 'Test1';
}
if (u > 179999) {
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 'Test2';
}
document.getElementById('output2').innerHTML = 'Test3' + j;
document.getElementById('output3').innerHTML = 'Test4 ' + u;
document.getElementById('output4').innerHTML = 'Test5 ' + preresult;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not make four input fields and one submit button instead of four input fields and four buttons? In order to perform your calculation shouldn't the user **must** fill all four fields?

Answer (score 0):

Looked into your code, it seems that you have made things way too much complicated that it should be. First of all, you don't call `submit` function on the input to get the value of it. If you want to get the value of `x` then you just access the `value` property like this `document.getElementById("x").value`. Secondly, you really don't need four buttons, all you need to do is **ONE** button that submits the form and adding `required` on input fields makes the browser not submit the form until all forms are filled. Last of all, `id` attribute needs to be unique across your page. You have both form and input field as id `a` which is unacceptable. It will show no error but get you in sorts of trouble. You can see what I did here, where I prevented the form from being submitted upon the button click and simply called the `calc` function to perform the calculation.

```
 <!DOCTYPEhtml>
<html>
<head>
<title>NatHisCalc</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1><center><b><p>Test</p></b></center></h1>
<center><b><p id='output'>loading...</p></b></center>
<center><b><p id='output2'>loading...</p></b></center>
<center><b><p id='output3'>loading...</p></b></center>
<center><b><p id='output4'>loading...</p></b></center>
<form onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); calc();" action="/action_page.php">
  Input X <input type="number" id="x" required><br><br>
  Input Y <input type="number" id="y" required><br><br>
  Input A <input type="number" id="a" required><br><br>
  Input B <input type="number" id="b" required><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<script>


function calc() {
  var x = document.getElementById("x").value;
  var y = document.getElementById("y").value;
  var a = document.getElementById("a").value;
  var b = document.getElementById("b").value;

  var u = (0.101*(y/100))*(480000*(a/100))            
  var j = (0.581*(x/100))*(120000*(b/100))  
  if (x > 150 || x < 50) {
  window.alert('Hold on... Those inputs will result in an unreasonable output. You can click ');
  }
  var preresult = j + u;
  if (preresult < 177000) {
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 'Test';
  } else {
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 'Test1';
  }
  if (u > 179999) {
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 'Test2';
  }
  document.getElementById('output2').innerHTML = 'Test3' + j;
  document.getElementById('output3').innerHTML = 'Test4 ' + u;
  document.getElementById('output4').innerHTML = 'Test5 ' + preresult;
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```